# Adding data to database ( gridview ) , refresh gridview to see the values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a gridview.

- I'm adding values with parameters->open connection->execute
  reader->connection close

But the problem is that the values added are not displayed in the    gridview and if I reload the page I still can't see them but    if I        click on the url textbox in the browser and press enter    then I see       the values added + 2/3 times the same values in    other rows ( because of reload ).

```
string cstring = "connection string";
string query = "Insert into table (Name) values (@Name)"; 
Sql conection conect    =    new sqlconnection(cstring);     
sqlcommand command = new sqlcommand(query,conect) ;                                               
command.parameters.addwithvalue("Name",name.text);           
conect.open();    
comanda.executeReader();   
conect.close
```

Comment: You can show the code that you used.

Comment: yep , sorry there were some issues .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this issue many times. In general, I've [disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate.aspx) the GridView's ViewState to fix the problem.

**Explanation**: On PostBack, GridView sees that it didn't update any data (though some other part of your code *did*), so it doesn't bother re-querying the database. Instead, it just reuses data from its ViewState.

Keep in mind that it is best to use GridView to update the DB rather than some other mechanism, and that is why you are encountering this problem.

Comment: Try disabling your GridView's ViewState.